# creation of new log file after a time interval by using python logging

Tags: python-3.x

Please give the clarification about why this below code is generating new file with log content but swap the content between base log file and newly created log file  after that given interval by using python logging

````
``` import os
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import time
current_dir = os.getcwd()
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(current_dir, os.pardir, os.pardir))
path_log = os.environ.get("PATH_LOG")

# Define the log format
FORMAT = "%(filename)s - line:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)2s() -%(levelname)s %  (asctime)-15s %(message)s"

# Create a logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Use TimedRotatingFileHandler to create a new log file every hour
fh = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path_log, when="S", interval=80, backupCount=7,   delay=True)  # Rotate every 5 minutes, keeping logs for 7 rotations
f = logging.Formatter(FORMAT)
fh.setFormatter(f)

# Add the handler to the logger
logger.addHandler(fh)

# Set the logger level
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Add a delay before emitting log messages
time.sleep(10)

# Emit a log message after the delay
logger.debug("This is a test log message ingest")```
````

Comment: I can see an typo in %  (asctime)-15s  -> %(asctime)-15s

Comment: Actually it is correct on my code.when i pasted here, an extra space were added.that's my mistake.